# Convert CSS Box to Rounded Corner?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I haven't dove into HTML for a while...I'm trying to convert this box into the same size/shape but with rounded corners. Looking at the Syntax for rounded-corners I'm not sure how to work with max-height/width in rounded corners?

Here are my current div tags:

```
    <div id="content" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
    <div style="max-height: 600px; max-width: 700px;">
    [content]
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the border-radius rule... there wont be issues.

```
<div style="max-height: 600px; max-width: 700px; border-radius: 10px;"></div>
```

or...

```
<div class="med-round"></div>
```

+

```
.med-round {
    max-height: 600px; 
    max-width: 700px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: errrr, much easier than I expected. That did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can use the border-radius property, but I want to add:

-don't forget to add the webkit prefix:

```
#content{
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

-don't forget to check if this or other features will work across browsers (border-radius doesn't work on IE8)

You might find these links useful:
http://caniuse.com/
http://css3generator.com/